# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode, react-native

Newly created(Oct-20) React native project iOS build fails with error in Xcode

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___darwin_check_fd_set_overflow", referenced from:
      _RAND_poll in libcrypto.a(rand_unix.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have another react native project which was created 2 month back (Aug-20), it build successfully in Xcode. I tried most of the methods, but still did not get it fix

I'm using Xcode Version 11.1 and MacOS Mojave Version 10.14.6

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the pod file(ios> Pods > OpenSSL-Universal). I tried to replace this folder from a working react-native project (not too old) and it worked perfectly.